# Ember - passing variable from route to controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, controller, ember-data

I have big trouble with EmberJS. I'm using Ember.RSVP.hash to load multiple of models like this:

**route:**

```
 model() {
    const self = this;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      test: 'sample text'
    }).then((hash) => {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        test: hash.test,
      });
    }, self);
  }
```

Then in my controller I'm trying to access this model param like this:

**controller:**

```
export default Controller.extend({
  init() {
   console.log(this.get('model.test');
  }
```

My console should log 'sample text' but unfortunately I'm getting *'undefined'*

Is this caused by init method I used? I want to notice that I need to have  access to this param immediately after loading this route page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `setupController` hook in route.js it will be called after model hook , so you will get `controller` and `model` instance in the argument, so you can get access to model properties and set controller properties based on `model`.

```
setupController(controller,model)
{
 controller.setProperites(model);
  //you can do anything with controller and model instance
}
```

`init` method will be called before you `model` hook finishing the execution so you can not access it `this.get('model.test')` like you did.

Comment: I forgot to write that I also have setupController like yours, but it still don't work in way that I expected.
Ok. Then how can I access this param?

Comment: Where do you want to access params ? ( ie., you mean the params is `model`)

Comment: @kamrza What do you want to do by accessing the `model.test` in controller ?. if you want this property in the template then you can directly access it. if you want to do some decoration to `model.test` then create computed property and return that value. you can use that computed property in template

Comment: I don't want to put property directly to template. I need to subscribe other array with this data, and this array is displayed in template as a list?

Comment: For your use case still you can use setupController or computed property in controller. if you can provide your attempt with the above approach we can improvise it.

Answer (score -1):

chances are that the parent Controller object needs to do some setup before you'll be able to access model attributes. Try the following:

**Controller**

```
export default Controller.extend({
    init() {
        // This line calls the Controller constructor...
        this._super(...arguments);
        console.log(this.get('model.test');
    }
});
```

[The Ember docs](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_init) might provide you with additional info you need.

Additionally, the controller is most likely to be constructed before your model promises have resolved. In that case you'll have to use [computed properties](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) that will update whenever the attributes relied on have changed value at the time you try to access the computed property.